# Minesweeper countdown

Tags: java, timer, countdown, minesweeper

//I am trying to set a timer for my minesweeper code using java, and below is my code for timer setting. It is supposed to be a 1000sec countdown, but somehow, the program will sometimes refresh and start over from 1050sec itself, which is very confusing. Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

```
   public Board(JLabel timeBar, JLabel statusBar) {
    ...
    startTime = LocalDateTime.now().getSecond();
    // set timer
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!gameOver) {
                int endTime = LocalDateTime.now().getSecond();
                int delta = endTime - startTime;
                if (delta >= 1000) {
                    gameOver = true;
                } else {
                    timeBar.setText(String.format("Time Remaining: %d", 1000 - delta));
                }
            }
        }
        
    }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Don't use a TimerTask. Updates to Swing components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Instead you should be using a Swing Timer.